# Merge two object based on id property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Original array getting from response:

```
result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three",
        d: "four",
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        a: "five",
        b: "six",
        c: "seven",
        d: "eight",
    }
]
```

I want result which is mentioned below. Please do the needful. Thanks in advance

```
newResult = [
    {
        id: 1,
        newArr: [{
            a: "one",
            b: "two",
            c: "three",
            d: "four",
        }, {
            a: "five",
            b: "six",
            c: "seven",
            d: "eight",
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: why the id = 1 after merged? and what if there are more object in the original result? like id 3 and 4

Comment: Free code generation feature at SO is available for premium users only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const obj = {};
result.forEach(t => obj[t.id] ? obj[t.id].push(t) : (obj[t.id] = [t]));
const transformed = Object.keys(obj).map(t => ({id: t, newArr: obj[t].map(el => 
{delete el.id; return el})}));
console.log(transformed);
```

```js
result = [
    {
        id: 1,
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three",
        d: "four",
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        a: "five",
        b: "six",
        c: "seven",
        d: "eight",
    },
        {
        id: 3,
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three",
        d: "four",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        a: "five",
        b: "six",
        c: "seven",
        d: "eight",
    },
        {
        id: 2,
        a: "one",
        b: "two",
        c: "three",
        d: "four",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        a: "five",
        b: "six",
        c: "seven",
        d: "eight",
    }
];
const obj = {};
result.forEach(t => obj[t.id] ? obj[t.id].push(t) : (obj[t.id] = [t]));
const transformed = Object.keys(obj).map(t => ({id: t, newArr: obj[t].map(el => {delete el.id; return el})}));
console.log(transformed);
```